# cannot conver 'int*' to 'card*' in assignment

Tags: c++

Hi I got some same errors in similar methods:

```
void Hand::addCard(card* card)
{
    if(Cards==NULL)
    {
        Cards=new card[1];
        Cards[0]=*card;
        return ;
    }
    int size=sizeof(Cards)/sizeof(card);

    card* d = new card[size];
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        d[i]=Cards[i];
    delete []Cards;
    Cards = new card[size+1];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        Cards[i] = d[i];
    Cards[size]= *card;
    delete []d;
}
```

in this code, error shows:

```
expected type-specifier before 'card'
cannot convert 'int*' to 'card*' in assignment
expected ';' before 'card'
'd' was not declared in this scope
```

All the errors appear in similar code such as:

```
Cards=new card[1];
card* d = new card[size];
Cards = new card[size+1];
```

in these lines.

also in `delete []d;` , there is another error:

```
type '<type error>' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer
```

`Cards` is `card* Cards` in `header`,
and that method is

```
public: void addCard(card*);
```

also `card` is `class card{...}`

I made other cpp and header quite well (there are no error)

so I think it's not relate with other class.

please give me any good idea or suggestion.

thank you guys!

Comment: `sizeof(Cards)/sizeof(card);` does not work for pointers to dynamic arrays!

Answer (score 4):

```
void Hand::addCard(card* card)
```

You are hiding the name of the type `card` with that of an instance of `card*` named `card`. Use a different name:

```
void Hand::addCard(card* foo)
```